# Export a graph to .eps file with R

Tags: r, graph, eps

How do I export a graph to an .eps format file? I typically export my graphs to a .pdf file (using the 'pdf' function), and it works quite well. However, now I have to export to .eps files.

Comment: You could try searching in R by typing `??eps`. You would either get `postscript` page or at least `ps.options` (which would lead you to `postscript`).

Comment: See also [pdf2ps](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#PDF) to convert pdf files to ps. Shell usage: `$ pdf2ps plot.pdf`, will create `plot.ps`.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The easiest way I've found to create postscripts is the following, using the `setEPS()` command:

```
setEPS()
postscript("whatever.eps")
plot(rnorm(100), main="Hey Some Data")
dev.off()
```

Comment: It's surprising how useful this is, and how hidden a feature it is.

Comment: Yes, saved me a lot of screenshot :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I got to get the graph in * .eps.

Answer (score 66):

If you are using `ggplot2` to generate a figure, then a `ggsave(file="name.eps")` will also work.

Comment: Ah, this is just what I needed!

And you can modify size like this: `ggsave("name.eps", width = 20, height = 20, units = "cm")`

Answer (score 33):

The `postscript()` device allows creation of EPS, but **only** if you change some of the default values. Read `?postscript` for the details.

Here is an example:

```
postscript("foo.eps", horizontal = FALSE, onefile = FALSE, paper = "special")
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks. I am tryin' to use it, but there is an error : graph margins too large...

Comment: make the plot dimensions bigger: `postscript("foo.eps", horizontal = FALSE, onefile = FALSE, paper = "special", height = 10, width = 10)` for example. The units are in inches. The problem is that the device you are plotting to is not large enough to contain the margins of the plot region you are using.

Comment: I needed the exported *.eps to work in Microsoft Powerpoint, which was not the case initially. After some trial and error I noticed I have to set additionally the parameter `colormodel="rgb"` of postscript().

Answer (score 17):

Another way is to use Cairographics-based SVG, PDF and PostScript Graphics Devices.
This way you don't need to `setEPS()`

```
cairo_ps("image.eps")
plot(1, 10)
dev.off()
```

Comment: This is a useful suggestion. `cairo_ps` differs from `postscript` in that it supports more unicode glyphs, but has the drawback that semi-transparency is poorly handled, and will often trigger bitmap rather than vector output.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, open a `postscript()` device with a filename ending in `.eps`, do your plot(s) and call `dev.off()`.