# output .eps graphics with 800 dpi

Tags: r, graphics, dpi, eps

A client needs graphics for a manuscript with .eps format and 800 dpi.

Usually I export to tiff using `tiff()` with a `res=` argument and everything is good. In fact I've never exported to .eps before so I've been googling around.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142842/export-a-graph-to-eps-file-with-r), which has gotten me to the .eps file stage (though I currently can't view the file I exported to make sure it looks right). But as far as a quick search via help in R-studio has given me, I can't change the dpi.

Any help? Current code looks much like:

```
setEPS()
postscript("whatever.eps", width = 7, height = 5)
plot(rnorm(100), main="Hey Some Data")
dev.off()
```

I'm used to `units="in"`, `res=800` being included so I don't even feel comfortable with the height and width args I've supplied and can't view the file to make sure it looks right.

Comment: Depending on how `postscript()` is saving the .eps file, it may or may not be a vector graphic. If it is, there's no real concept of DPI.

Comment: Can you expand on 'Depending on how it's saved'? It was my initial understanding that it was a vector graphic so it wouldn't have dpi, but then the journal specified the dpi for .eps as 800 so I figured I was wrong.

So sometimes it has dpi (bitmapped graphic?) and sometimes its a vector graphic? Sorry, graphical output methods is nowhere near my specialty.

Comment: Take a look [at this article](http://vector-conversions.com/vector/is_eps_vector.html), which may be helpful. It's not really my specialty either.

Comment: You could use `cairo_ps` from `Cairo` package, which takes the `fallback_resolution` argument.