# Cannot save ggplot as eps

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676085/saving-two-ggplots-in-grid-arrange-to-eps-file-format) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142842/export-a-graph-to-eps-file-with-r) but ***cannot*** make it work.

```
vDF <- data.frame(v = rnorm(50,1,40))
g <- ggplot(vDF, aes(x = vDF)) + geom_histogram()
ggsave(g, file="name.eps")
```

I keep getting the error

> Error in grDevices::postscript(..., onefile = FALSE, horizontal = FALSE,  : 
>         cannot open file 'name.eps'

Why can't I make this work? I've see advice saying 'hey just do...

```
setEPS()
postscript("whatever.eps")
plot(rnorm(100), main="Hey Some Data")
dev.off()
```

But I can't even save the original .eps file in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there's an error in your code. It should be:

```
vDF <- data.frame(v = rnorm(50,1,40))
g <- ggplot(vDF, aes(x = v)) + geom_histogram()
```

(note the `aes`).

Now, to save the plot as `eps`, you have to use the option `device=eps` in `ggsave`:

```
ggsave(g, file="name.eps", device="eps")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20694434)

Comment: @VasimVanzara Why do you say that does not provide an answer? That doesn't work? For me the question was clear and this is the answer.

Comment: You should add a some explanation. If you want to try something you can ask same in comment.

Comment: @VasimVanzara Ah I see there's an error. I edit. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Stephane Laurent. Embarrassing coding error. However even after I fixed that it still did not work. Then shifted to my laptop and it worked fine. It seems my difficulties may be related to permissions for creating image files on my work server rather than an error with ggplot or myself. Anyway this is handy to know, thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

Discovered how to do this properly

```
ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "foo.eps",
                plot = foo,
                device = cairo_ps)
```

specifying `cairo_ps` for the device is the key

Answer (score 0):

None of the above works for me. I had to specify the font in the ggsave()

```
    ggsave(filename = "fig1.eps", plot=fig1,family="Times")
```