# Saving ggplot as .eps

Tags: r, ggplot2

My issues with producing publication-grade figures in ggplot continue (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031842/cannot-save-ggplot-as-eps))

Here's some reproducible code that throws the error.

```
library(bayesplot)
df <- data.frame(xVar = rnorm(1e4,0,1))
t <- bayesplot::mcmc_trace(df,"xVar")
t
```

[image]

All good. But when I try to save the figure as an eps (which many journals demand)

```
ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "tPlot.eps", 
                plot = t1, 
                device = "eps", 
                dpi = 1200, 
                width = 15,
                height = 10, 
                units = "cm")
```

I get the error

```
Error in grid.Call(C_stringMetric, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label)) : 
  family 'serif' not included in postscript() device
```

Has anyone encountered this sort of problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fonts in plots is a tricky topic in `R`. You might either not have the font or `R` simply can't find it. You can look into the `extrafont` package and try to hunt down the font on your system or download it. I would rather suggest to simply choose a different theme though:

```
library(bayesplot)
df <- data.frame(xVar = rnorm(1e4,0,1))
t <- bayesplot::mcmc_trace(df,"xVar") +
  ggplot2::theme_bw()
t

ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "tPlot.eps", 
                plot = t, 
                device = "eps", 
                dpi = 1200, 
                width = 15,
                height = 10, 
                units = "cm")
```

This got rid of the error on my machine.