# Installing fonts so that R postscript() device can recognise them

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, extrafont

Based on the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478128/saving-ggplot-as-eps) post I am trying to get the serif font (or 'family' of fonts) installed into R so that I can save ggplots as .eps files. Though the suggestion provided worked I would like to try to resolve the issue for future use.

Here's code to generate the issue.

```
library(bayesplot)
df <- data.frame(xVar = rnorm(1e4,0,1), yVar = rnorm(1e4,2,1), zVar = rnorm(1e4,4,1))
t <- bayesplot::mcmc_trace(df) 
t
```

[image]

Now when I go to save the figure...

```
ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "tPlot.eps", 
                plot = t, 
                device = "eps", 
                dpi = 1200, 
                width = 15,
                height = 10, 
                units = "cm")
```

...it throws the error

```
Error in grid.Call(C_stringMetric, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label)) : 
  family 'serif' not included in postscript() device
```

In the previous post the answerer suggested I download the `extrafont` package.

I ran

```
View(fonttable())
```

But the serif font did not appear to be installed.

Then I tried

```
font_addpackage(pkg = "serif")
```

But I got the error

```
Error in font_addpackage(pkg = "serif") : 
  Unknown font package type: not type1 or ttf.
```

Does anyone know how to install the serif font so R can recognise/use it?

Comment: [Serif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif) is not a font, it's a type of feature fonts may have or not.

Comment: @Rui Barradas you are right but the error message I copied into the post seems to indicate that R sees it a 'family', whatever that means. Do you have any tips on how to install it?

Comment: I don't interpret the error message the same way you do. I think it means that `"serif"` is not recognized as a font type. But there are 458 serif fonts in package `extrafont`, try `fnt <- fonts();i <- grep("serif", fnt, ignore.case = TRUE);fnt[i]` to have a vector of their names.

Comment: thank you @Rui Barradas. I used your code and got  `[1] "Microsoft Sans Serif"    "MS Reference Sans Serif"` which I gather are not serif fonts. Times New Roman is a serif font though, and when I do `View(fonttable())` Times New Roman is there, but I still get that error message. Also `View(fonttable())` only returns 81 font names. I am very confused about the difference between loading, embedding, and installing fonts. How do I install the 458 fonts you mention so that R can recognise them?

Comment: Have you read the package [documentation](https://github.com/wch/extrafont)?

Comment: Just the helps for each command. Didn't get anywhere. This helps. Thank you again @Rui Barradas.

Comment: Have you run `font_import()`? It's needed to install the fonts. After running it your `ggsave` code is not giving me errors.

Comment: Yes it did @Rui Barradas! It didn't yeaterday, Very strange, Oh well. Thank you. Put it in an answer, any answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to help, that's what SO is about :). See if the answer is what you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With package `extrafont` the fonts must be installed before being made available to users. This is done with function `font_import`.

```
library(extrafont)

font_import()    # This takes several minutes
```

Now we can see what are the fonts installed and available. From the documentation, `help("fonts")`.

> **Description**
>
> Show the fonts that are registered in the font table (and available for embedding)

```
fonts_installed <- fonts()

serif1 <- grepl("serif", fonts_installed, ignore.case = TRUE)
sans1 <- grepl("sans", fonts_installed, ignore.case = TRUE)

fonts_installed[serif1 & !sans1]

sum(serif1 & !sans1)
#[1] 458
```

There are 458 fonts available.
Another way to see the font table is with function `fonttable` but the fonts returned are not necessarily available for embedding. From `help("fonttable")`.

> **Description**
>
> Returns the full font table

Note that the function returns a dataframe, hence the call to `str` below (output omitted).

```
df_font <- fonttable()
str(df_font)

serif2 <- grepl("serif", df_font$FontName, ignore.case = TRUE)
sans2 <- grepl("sans", df_font$FontName, ignore.case = TRUE)

df_font$FontName[serif2 & !sans2]
```

Finally see if the graphing functions work on a postscript device.

```
library(bayesplot)

df <- data.frame(xVar = rnorm(1e4,0,1), yVar = rnorm(1e4,2,1), zVar = rnorm(1e4,4,1))
p <- bayesplot::mcmc_trace(df)
p

ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "tPlot.eps", 
                plot = p, 
                device = "eps", 
                dpi = 1200, 
                width = 15,
                height = 10, 
                units = "cm")
```

Comment: When I run this it successfully registers the fonts, yet when I see those that are available for embedding I only get two options. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @corsica No, I cannot say I do. Maybe ask another question with a link to this question and the code you have run?