# Labels and legend do not appear when saving a postscript file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use `dev.copy2eps()` function to save my outputted charts. However, when I change the plot width and height in the function, all the strings (including labels and legend) do not appear.

Example of an outputted plot (with non-default sizes):
[image]

Code:

```
boxplot(volunteers$number_of_commits, employees$number_of_commits, las = 1, outline = FALSE, cex.lab=1.2, horizontal = TRUE, margin = list(l = 10, r = 10, b = 0, t = 0), col=(c("#b8d1ed", "#aae0c0")), main = "Number of Commits")
legend("bottomright", legend=c("Employees", "Volunteers"), fill=c("#aae0c0", "#b8d1ed"), inset= .02, cex=1.1)
dev.copy2eps(file="Images/atom/atom_num_commits.eps", width = 650, height = 360)
```

The question is: How can I save my chart in different sizes using the postscript function, maintaining the same quality and information?

Comment: hello try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142842/export-a-graph-to-eps-file-with-r

Comment: Works for me. I'm opening it with Inkscape. What do you open it with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: your `height` and `width` parameters seem to be the problem.

It turns out that the labels are not removed if you add `height` and `width` **BUT EXTREMELY SMALL**. By removing these, you will be able to see the labels in the eps, or consider using significantly smaller values.

```
plot(cars$speed~cars$dist)
legend("bottomright", legend=c("Employees", "Volunteers"), fill=c("#aae0c0", "#b8d1ed"), inset= .02, cex=1.1)
dev.copy2eps(file = "your_path/test.eps")
```

The output of your EPS plot will have the same aspect ratio of height and width as you plotting device (in RGUI or RStudio). You can add the parameters to maintain aspect ratio, but reduce the magnitude of their values. Please see this section from `?dev.copy2eps`:

> If `dev.print` is used with a specified device (even `postscript`) it sets the width and height in the same way as `dev.copy2eps`. This will not be appropriate unless the device specifies dimensions in inches, in particular not for `png`, `jpeg`, `tiff` and `bmp` unless `units = "inches"` is specified.

Another solution, in which you can also directly adjust the width and height (in **inches**, so you might think of the magnitude) [was proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8147482/3250126) in [s.brunel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5790454/s-brunel)'s comment:

```
setEPS()
postscript("C:/Users/weig_mi/Desktop/test2.eps", width = 6.5, height = 3.60)
plot(cars$speed~cars$dist)
legend("bottomright", legend=c("Employees", "Volunteers"), fill=c("#aae0c0", "#b8d1ed"), inset= .02, cex=1.1)
dev.off()
```

From `?postscript` we learn that `width` and `height` are

> the width and height of the graphics region in inches.